# shiny_prerendered document using reactiveFileReader

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the `learnr` package to create some exercise questions. So, here is the situation: I have a csv file inside a googlesheet that I'd like to use `reactiveFileReader` to continuously import. My code is in a RMarkdown with this YAML

```
---
title: "Tutorial"
output: 
  learnr::tutorial:
    progressive: true
    allow_skip: true
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---
```

Question: How do I use `reactiveFileReader` inside this RMarkdown?

I tried to assign the `reactiveFileReader` to an object, but I get this error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plan is for the students to use this data in the learnr exercises, trying to load it as a reactive is not a good idea as they would not be able to use it as a regular dataframe.

If the data is in a google sheet, I would advise using the `googlesheets` package to import it as a static dataset everytime the tutorial is loaded.

First, to get an auth token your app can use remotely when you deploy it run this code with the app directory as your working directory

```
library(googlesheets)

shiny_token <- gs_auth() # authenticate w/ your desired Google identity here
saveRDS(shiny_token, "shiny_app_token.rds") # save token to app dir
```

Then in the code for the learnr tutorial load in the data using you auth token and the sheet key for your google sheet (find this in the URL for the sheet)

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
library(googlesheets)

googlesheets::gs_auth(token = "shiny_app_token.rds")
sheet_key <- "your_sheet_key_here"
learnr_data <- googlesheets::gs_key(sheet_key) %>% gs_read_csv()
```
````

`learnr_data` should now be available to all your exercise chunks as a regular dataframe.